# Entity Framework IoC Integration (Spring.net)

Tags: entity-framework, spring.net

I Need to configure Entity Framework in Conjunction with NCommon to work with Spring.NET IoC Container.
I Noticed about the Microsoft CommonServiceLocator project to abstract DI Containers used in the NCommon project, but I can't still find an exaustive example of how implementing NCommon Repository for Entity Framework using Spring.NET as IoC all configured by Xml.
Any Idea?
Thanks in advance.